# In spite of setting IsDeleteble Property as "IsDeletable = true" I Can't delete chip

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

In spite of setting IsDeletable property as IsDeletable=True,
 I kept clicking the chip delete icon but nothing happened.
How Can I delete chip clicking delete icon?

mainwindow.xaml

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="addchip">
        <Button Click="create_chip">delete_chip</Button>
        <materialDesign:Chip
  Content="Example Chip"
  ToolTip="This is an example chip" IsDeletable="True"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

mainwindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void deletenotify(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("delete!");

    }

    private void create_chip(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Chip a = new Chip();
        a.Content = "Example Chip";
        a.IsDeletable =true ;
        a.DeleteClick += deletenotify;
        addchip.Children.Add(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Output:

[image]

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestChipDeleting.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="400" 
        Width="300"
        Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl Name="UsersListBox">

        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System.Windows;
using MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;

namespace TestChipDeleting
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BindUsers();
        }

        private void Chip_OnDeleteClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var currentChip = (Chip) sender;
            UsersListBox.Items.Remove(currentChip);
        }

        private void BindUsers()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var chip = new Chip {IsDeletable = true};
                chip.DeleteClick += Chip_OnDeleteClick;
                chip.Content = "Username" + i;
                chip.Icon = i;
                UsersListBox.Items.Add(chip);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me perfectly!Thank you for telling me detailed code kindly.